# Explode date and string in SQL server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, explode, sqlsrv

I have converted my database from mysql to SQL server and working on exploding date and time. I am getting error: `explode() expects parameter 2 to be string,` This is the code:

```
while($r = sqlsrv_fetch_array  ($sth)) 
    {

        //$temp = array();
        // assumes dates are in the format "yyyy-MM-dd"

        $dateString = $r['date'];
        $dateArray = explode('-', $dateString);
        $year = $dateArray[0];
        $month = $dateArray[1] - 1; // subtract 1 to convert to javascript's 0-indexed months
        $day = $dateArray[2];

        var_dump($dateString);

        // assumes time is in the format "hh:mm:ss"
        $timeString = $r['time'];
        $timeArray = explode(':', $timeString);
        $hours = $timeArray[0];
        $minutes = $timeArray[1];
        $seconds = $timeArray[2];

        var_dump($timeString);

        $temp = array();
        $temp[] = array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds)"); 
        $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Temperatur']);


        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);

    }
```

When I do var_dump on the variables $dateString and $timeString I get, the first one shows the dateString and second timeString( PS: In my SQL server date is saved as date and time is saved as type (0):

[image]

This is how it looks when I do it against my mysql database, which is correct[image]:

Comment: Please edit your previous question and add the new information instead of creating the same one again.

Comment: I've edited but no help :(

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
explode(":", $r['time']->format("H:i:s"));
```